# MVC Web.config 301 redirect for all urls containing a set url segment

Tags: c#, redirect, web-config, umbraco

I'm changing the URL format for a section of my website. all `##host##/blog/##article-name## will need become ##host##/news/##article-name##`.

In Umbraco, I can redirect each individual page from within the CMS, but for efficiency, I'd like to set this particular redirect as a rule on a more permanent level.

```
<rule name="Redirect from blog to news" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^blog/(.*)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="^news/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

When I run this it's redirecting to this URL `##host##/%5Enews/blog/##article-name##`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of trial and error I have solved the issue. I hope this is helpful to somebody else. The issue was some unnecessary characters in my match query and redirect string.

```
<rule name="Redirect from blog to news" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="news{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Yes, the main issue was the `^` anchor at the start of the redirect - that part isn't a regex, just a string with replacements. The original match of `^blog/` would also have left requests to just `blog` being handled by Umbraco.